# Fazer download direto sem reprodução

Tags: html, html5

Tenho um arquivo HTML onde existe alguns links para download, porém alguns links não estão fazendo o download em si mas abrindo no próprio browser, como arquivos .txt e .mp3, arquivos como .rar e .zip são baixados direto, como faço para que todos os arquivos sejam baixados diretamente (sem serem reproduzidos)?

**OBS:** Chrome última versão.

```
        <html>
       <head>
           <title>
                    Downloads
           </title>
         </head>
        <body>
            <a href="teste.txt">TXT</a>
            <a href="teste.rar">RAR</a>
            <a href="teste.mp3">MP3</a>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você controla o servidor onde esses arquivos ficam hospedados? Se sim, sabe qual é o servidor?

Comment: @ctgPi, Não controlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você não controla o servidor, a solução é usar o [atributo `download="…"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) do HTML5:

```
<a href="teste.txt" download="laranja.txt">TXT</a>
<a href="teste.rar" download="morango.rar">RAR</a>
<a href="teste.mp3" download="banana.mp3">MP3</a>
```

Isso funciona no Chrome e no Firefox, mas não funciona em nenhuma versão do IE.